# LEDs won't turn on

Tags: lighting, led, garage-door-opener, motion-sensor

I have a garage door opener which can have two lightbulbs screwed, that for some reason burn out LED lightbulbs approximately every 3 months. However, this time, the new LED bulbs I bought work everywhere in my house but in this garage door opener. I usually only have one bulb in at once and it's always worked fine. These new bulbs are partitioned into quarters it seems, whereas the old ones where completely covered in a rubber like substance making hard to see inside.

The old LED's used 75mA and the new ones 93mA.

What could be wrong that these won't work?

Comment: The control board of the door operator probably has a Silicone Controlled Rectifier (SCR) that isn’t completely compatible with LED lamps because it relies on current leakage through the turned off lamp, which works with incandescent but not all LEDs.   Newer more expensive name brand LED bulbs (that use a passive current resistor to improve dimming) may (or may not) work better than cheap generic LED bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

Garage door openers need a vibration resistant bulb. Are all screw-in Edison base LEDs vibration resistant? Are the LEDs that you found didn't last long listed for garage door openers?

See [Genie LED Garage Door Opener Light Bulb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IHHVZTW)

I have always used vibration resistant incandescent bulbs in our opener and they last a long time. The cumulative on cycle in a garage door opener is so short that the energy consumption of an incandescent bulb is negligible. However, the waste heat from these may damage the plastic cover over time. I usually have only one bulb in the opener.

Whenever I had a screw base receptacle which was not working properly, I always suspected that the center (springy) contact was not making good contact so my SOP was and is to bend the center contact out from the base. I used to use a small crochet hook, but now I use a small screwdriver to pry up on the center contact. If the contact is corroded I would also scrub it with an abrasive eraser, but an ordinary pencil eraser will do a lot. Try that and see if the non working LED then works.